# Is this simple SQL query correct?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query below is pretty self-explanatory, and although I'm not good at SQL, I can't find anything wrong with it. However, the number it yields in not in accordance with my gut feeling and I would like it double-checked, if this is appropriate for StackOverflow.

I'm simply trying to get the number of users that joined my website in 2020, **and also** made a payment in 2020. I'm trying to figure out "new revenue".

This is the query:

```sql
SELECT Count(DISTINCT( auth_user.id )) AS "2020" 
FROM   auth_user 
       JOIN subscription_transaction 
         ON ( subscription_transaction.event = 'one-time payment' 
              AND subscription_transaction.user_id = auth_user.id 
              AND subscription_transaction.timestamp >= '2020-01-01' 
              AND subscription_transaction.timestamp <= '2020-12-31' ) 
WHERE  auth_user.date_joined >= '2020-01-01' 
       AND auth_user.date_joined <= '2020-12-31';
```

I use PostgreSQL 10.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, it is rather hard to know what you find inaccurate.

Comment: The parentheses around the column name inside the count function are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the query using `EXISTS` to get rid of the `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT count(*) AS "2020" 
FROM  auth_user au
WHERE au.date_joined >= '2020-01-01' AND
      au.date_joined < '2021-01-01' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM subscription_transaction st
              WHERE st.event = 'one-time payment' AND
                    st.user_id = au.id AND
                    st.timestamp >= '2020-01-01' AND
                    st.timestamp < '2021-01-01'
             ) ;
```

This should be faster than your version.  However, the results should be the same.

Comment: Perhaps this is what the best solution is use of `EXISTS` to check values of 1 table into another. Just saw now that the OP doesnt require extra columns of the other table rather just as a reference. Hence, no join is required

Comment: Thanks, however, as you said, I get the same result: a number that doesn't match my gut feeling about the business. But my gut feeling could be wrong! Just wanted to make sure that this query does what I described.

Comment: I think that this simpler query without the JOIN is must more straightforward and the number it yields must be correct. The number of users who joined in 2020 and made a payment in 2020. My gut feeling was wrong then :)